# How to call same API with different data, multiple times using retrofit?

Tags: android, api, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

The scenario is that I'm loading products using the category ID's. Therefore I have made a for loop to call the API multiple times.

```
for (category in response.body()!!.categories) {
                        getProductByCategory(category)
                    }
```

The problem is that sometimes i loose data in getProductByCategory API and sometimes the order of data changes.
What I want is that my API's get called 1 after the other but not before the previous API is completely executed.
The limitation is I cannot use the `.execute()` as I want my API's to be asynchronous.

```
private fun getProductByCategory(category: CategoriesModel) {
    RetrofitClient.instance.productByCategory(category.id)
        .enqueue(object : Callback<ProductsInCategory> {
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<ProductsInCategory>,
                response: Response<ProductsInCategory>
            ) {
                //dialog.hide()
                //Log.e("TAG", "Product by Category Response: " + response.toString())
                if (response.body() != null) {
                    arrayProducts = response.body()!!.products
                    array.add(AllProductsModel(category, arrayProducts))
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<ProductsInCategory>, t: Throwable) {
                Toast.makeText(context, t.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                Log.e("TAG", "Failed Response: " + t.message)
                Log.e("TAG", "Failed Response Localized: " + t.localizedMessage)
                dialog.hide()
            }
        })
}
```

I'm not sure if I should use a runnable thread in this situation or an async task or any other method involving observable.

Comment: Any solution to this?

Comment: I had to call it multiple times! Added multiple checks got no proper solution!

Answer (score 1):

```
You can do something like this.

 list.forEach {
           coroutineScope { 
               async {  
                   
                       val result =   abcrepository.xyzapi(it)
                       when (result) {
                           is Result.Error -> {
                              
                           }
                           else -> {}
                       }
                   } else {
                      
                   }
               }.await()
           }
        }
```